# How to include a header in file of sub-folder in SQF?

Tags: sqf

I have a mission with the following structure

```
init.sqf
    radio/script1.sqf
    radio/script2.sqf
script3.sqf
macros.hpp
```

in `script3.sqf`, I can use `#include "macros.hpp"`. However, I am not being able to do the same in `script1.sqf`, as it causes the game to crash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `radio/script1.sqf`, you can include "macros.hpp" using

```
#include "../macros.hpp"
```

This is reported in [this PDF](http://ofp-faguss.com/files/ofp_preprocessor_explained.pdf), in section 4, "#include".

They use the other slash `\`, but I tested in arma 3 that `/` works.

Notice that if you add

```
#include "../macros.hpp"
```

to `script3.sqf`, the game will crash, and the error message is what you would expect. Specifically, it can be `radio/macros.hpp` not found.